# ItextSharper PDF to Html Convert

Tags: c#, dll, itext

I should convert PDF File to Html File. I'm coding a library using itextSharper. I found codes about it but with this code its only convert texts in PDF. I need to convert all page(image tables and another things) How can I do that.

This is my code:

```
  using System.IO;
  using iTextSharp.text.pdf; 
  using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

public class PdfToHtmlManager
{
    public string ConvertPdf(string inputFileName, string outputFileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputFileName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputFileName))
        {
            return "File name error";
        }
        else if (!File.Exists(inputFileName)) 
        {
            return "File is not exist";
        }
        else 
        {
            PdfReader pr = new PdfReader(inputFileName); 

            int maxPage = pr.NumberOfPages;
            pr.Close();
            StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter(outputFileName, true, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            int page = 1;

            while (page<=maxPage)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy its = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFileName);

                outFile.Write(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its));
                reader.Close();
                page++;

            }

            outFile.Close();
        }
        return "success";
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as iTextSharper. It used to be called iTextSharp, not iTextSharper. *It used to be called that way,* but that's no longer the case. Nowadays, it's called iText for .NET, and you're using an old version. The current version is iText 7. Finally, you think you can convert any PDF to HTML, but that's a wrong assumption. Before you ask this question, you should answer one important question from us: **Is your PDF a Tagged PDF?** If the answer to this question is **yes, it is**, we may be able to help you. If you don't know what Tagged PDF is, you should study PDF first.

Comment: Oh I see thats your program and name is important sorry about that( I correct spell at the hashtag part ). I have a PDF file which has tagged PDF, can I convert this to html or cant, thats my question.. shouldnt I use streamwriter,  and iText 7dll need a license?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie How can i do with itext7?